# App freezes due to reaching maxPoolSize

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am having problems where my web application freezes up.  Using the JConsole monitoring tools I see that the app is reaching maxPoolSize.  Which is causing the app to freeze up.

There's about 20 users on the system, and each user can have multiple web sessions.

Here's an example of a HttpServlet in the app.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Session sess = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        sess = RuntimeContext.getCurrentSession();
        tx = sess.beginTransaction();
        doingStuffWithSession(req, res, sess);
        if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {
            tx.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e, req, sess);
    } finally {
        if (sess != null && sess.isOpen() && tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
              tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my hibernate properties in c3p0:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="20" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="200" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are holding Sessions open (in your RuntimeContext), rather than opening and close()ing them upon each use. Sessions wrap Connections; if you don't close your Sessions you will exhaust the pool. committing or rolling back the transaction is not sufficient.

you should open a new Session for each client, and close it immediately when the client is done. see e.g. the idiom presented here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm